# Trying to get current location using GoogleApiClient is not Working

Tags: android, google-api-client

I have a simple project with `GoogleApiClient` to get a Latitude and Longitude and I'm struggling to make it work. This is what I have so far...

Gradle :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener....

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;...

private synchronized void callConnection() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i("LOG", "onConnected(" + bundle +  ")");
    try{
        Location l = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if(l != null){
            Log.i("LOG","latitude: " + l.getLatitude());
            Log.i("LOG","longitude: " + l.getLongitude());
        }
    }catch (SecurityException ex){
        Toast.makeText(this, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i("LOG","onConnectionSuspended(" + i + ")");

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i("LOG","onConnectionSuspended(" + connectionResult + ")");
}
```

And the Result Log is null, I'm not sure what could be, maybe the Permission ?Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Api Marshmallow and above give run time permission as:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
   // do your work
} else {
//  request permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
{
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] 
permissions, int[] grantResults) {
if (requestCode == MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE) {
  if (permissions.length == 1 &&
      permissions[0] == Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION &&
      grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
 /// granted do your work
 } else {
  // Permission was denied. Display an error message.
 }
}
```